# Italian & Italian-American Internment camp locations in the United States in WWII

Tags: world-war-two, geography

So I am making a Power Point for my American History class, and I cannot for the life of me find a map marking Italian American internment camps.  I found German American and Japanese American Interment camp maps, but that is it.

Comment: Just wondering - why did you think in the first place that such camps had existed?

Answer (score 3):

Reading between the lines of various online sources (mostly Wikipedia articles, unfortunately) it appears that Italian-American internees did not have dedicated camps, but instead were housed with German-American and Japanese-American internees as convenient.

It also appears that, due to the vigorous lobbying by the Italian Labour movement (and undoubtedly by it's (unnamed here) underworld associates), the only Italian-Americans actually interned were those for which evidence existed of malfeasance or doubtful loyalty. In consequence the number of Italian-American internees may have been less than 2,000 (though many more than that were required to register in the early days of 1942).

There have long been rumours that the Feds negotiated with the Mafia for it's loyalty through 1942 and 1943, in exchange for some concessions to senior members such as Charlie (Lucky) Luciano.